# Cooking a chicken and vegetable curry using a curry paste

Tags: substitutions, curry

Can I substitute green Harissa paste for Thai green curry paste in a chicken curry and in what proportions?

Answer (score 3):

No, those two things don't taste the same. They may have a few ingredients in common, but there are plenty of differences too. (Just look up a few recipes and this should be abundandly obvious.) You could certainly use harissa as a base for some kind of soupy dish similar to curry, but it wouldn't be Thai green curry.